# Only plotting observed dates in matplotlib, skipping range of dates

Tags: matplotlib

I have a simple dataframe I am plotting in `matplotlib`. However, the plot is showing the range of the dates, rather than just the two observed data points.

How can I only plot the two data points and not the range of the dates?

**df structure:**

```
Date                  Number
2018-01-01 12:00:00   1  
2018-02-01 12:00:00   2
```

**Output of the `matplotlib` code:**

[image: Boxplot]

**Here is what I expected** (this was done using a string and not a date on the x-axis data):
[image]

**df code:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['2018-01-01 12:00:00', 1], ['2018-02-01 12:00:00',2]], columns=['Date', 'Number'])  
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])  
df.set_index(['Date'],inplace=True)
```

**Plot code:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(
    figsize=(4,5), 
    dpi=72
)

width = 0.75

#starts the bar chart creation
ax1.bar(df.index, df['Number'], 
        width, 
        align='center', 
        color=('#666666', '#333333'), 
        edgecolor='#FF0000',
        linewidth=2
       ) 
ax1.set_ylim(0,3)
ax1.set_ylabel('Score')

fig.autofmt_xdate()

#Title
plt.title('Scores by group and gender')

plt.tight_layout() 
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding something like:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

myFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%y-%m-%d')
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)
plt.xticks(df.index)
```

[image: correct_figure]

I think the dates are transformed to large integers at the time of the plot. So `width = 0.75` is very small, try something bigger (like `width = 20`:

[image: another_plot]

Answer (score 0):

Matplotlib bar plots are numeric in nature. If you want a categorical bar plot instead, you may use pandas bar plots.

```
df.plot.bar()
```

You may then want to beautify the labels a bit

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['2018-01-01 12:00:00', 1], ['2018-02-01 12:00:00',2]], columns=['Date', 'Number'])  
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])  
df.set_index(['Date'],inplace=True) 

ax = df.plot.bar()
ax.tick_params(axis="x", rotation=0)
ax.set_xticklabels([t.get_text().split()[0] for t in ax.get_xticklabels()])

plt.show()
```

[image]